# Why does numpy.isin() behaves different when passed numpy.nan as a value?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to check if a set of values are in a numpy array. While doing this I found `np.isin()` behaves differently if the value passed is `np.nan`. That is:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([2, np.nan])

print(np.isin(2, a))
print(np.isin(np.nan, a))
```

output:

```
True
False
```

I have two questions:

How do I check if `np.nan` is in an array?

Why does these two values behave differently when passed to `np.isin()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rough equivalent is

```
 any([x == np.nan for x in a.flat])
```

Which will fail because nan is not even equal with itself. This oddity is not specific to numpy:

```
>>> float('nan') in [float('nan')]
False
```

> How do I check if np.nan is in an array?

Use `np.isnan(a).any()` instead.